# Setting up users on a LAMP server properly

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, lamp

I just started running a LAMP server with an AMI from turnkeylinux.com.

It is running on AWS, all is well, pretty simple to just get things going.

Now, I want to host multiple sites on this server, and I've figured that out too.  The place I really run into problems with is giving users appropriate access to via SFTP.

I can create a user than can log in, but can't figure out how to actually let them change certain files or folders in their home folder.

For example:

I am logged in as root, getting things set up.  I create /var/www/site1.com and upload a bunch of files.  I have set up my DNS and VHosts so that if I go to www.site1.com it works, excellent.

I have created a user named User1 and made them a member of the users group.  and then done

```
chown -R User1:www-data /var/www
```

It seems to work, but I'm just not sure that this was the RIGHT was to do it.  And is this how I should continue to manage the sites.  It has made all of the files 755.  I'm new to linux, so any advice on how to proceed is appreciated.

Comment: chown does not set the RWX rights of files, you must have also done a chmod at some point. Also, setting the rights of /var/www doesn't really have anything to do with granting SFTP rights, per-se.

Comment: Off topic; belongs on Serverfault or Webmasters.

Answer (score 1):

The "right" way depends on a lot of factors, but the simplest case where:

1) The webserver runs as www-data and needs to display pages in /var/www/*/*

2) The users need to be able to write to their own folders

So lets say you have `/var/www/user1` with site1 and user2 with `/var/www/
site2`

A way to acheive what you want is to have all files owned by group :www-data throughout the /var/www folder heirachy

```
chown :www-data /var/www -R
```

And individual folders and files owned by the respective user:

```
chown user1 /var/www/site1 -R
```

Then you can use 640 permissions for files (owner: read-write, group: read, universal: nothing)
And 750 for directories (owner: read-write-execute, group: read-execute, universal: nothing)

It gets more involved if you want to be able to upload files via websites for example...